# Salesforce Visual Flow lockdown

Tags: salesforce

Is there any way to deploy a visual flow as a managed package where the contents cannot be changed or viewed similar to apex code in a managed package?

If I elect to do it in apex, how do I create the managed locked down package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm?search_text=protection) article flows don't support intellectual property protection. Flows supports only the following values:

- Upgradeable. Flow is updated to a newer version when a package is upgraded.
- Subscriber Deletable. A subscriber or installer of a package can delete the flow.

Flows don't support IP protection.

> **IP Protection**
>
> Certain components automatically include intellectual
>   property protection, such as obfuscating Apex code. The only
>   exceptions are Apex methods declared as global, meaning that the
>   method signatures can be viewed by the subscriber. The information in
>   the components you package and publish might be visible to users on
>   AppExchange. Use caution when adding your code to a custom s-control,
>   formula, Visualforce page, or any other component that you cannot hide
>   in your app.

So source of flows will be visible in subscriber organization

if you select to implement logic in apex code, apex supports intellectual property protection and source will not be viisble for subscriber.